# How to define a polygonal region in 2D to subsequently integrate over it?

Tags: numerical-integration, regions

I want to integrate a function `f[x,y]` over a region like this.

[image]

Is there any way to define the region using the vertices of the purple polygon?

Then I can subsequently perform `NIntegrate[f[x,y],{x, y} ∈ region]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example in 12.2.

```
poly = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {1, 1/Sqrt[3]}, {1, 0}}];
NIntegrate[Log[x + y + 1], {x, y} \[Element] poly]
```

> `0.366623`

Let us verify it by

```
Integrate[Log[x + y + 1], {x, y} \[Element] poly]
```

> `-((36 - 12 Sqrt[3] + 12 Log[2] + 228 Sqrt[3] Log[2] + 138 Log[3] +  54 Sqrt[3] Log[3] + 9 Log[4] - 3 Sqrt[3] Log[4] +  48 Sqrt[3] Log[6] - 2 Log[8] - 2 Sqrt[3] Log[8] +  2 Sqrt[3] Log[9] - 48 Sqrt[3] Log[2 - 2/Sqrt[3]] +  90 Log[2 - Sqrt[3]] + 54 Sqrt[3] Log[2 - Sqrt[3]] -  90 Log[3 - Sqrt[3]] - 54 Sqrt[3] Log[3 - Sqrt[3]] -  180 Log[-1 + Sqrt[3]] - 108 Sqrt[3] Log[-1 + Sqrt[3]] +  72 Log[1 + Sqrt[3]] - 48 Sqrt[3] Log[1 + Sqrt[3]] -  36 Log[2 + Sqrt[3]] + 24 Sqrt[3] Log[2 + Sqrt[3]] -  18 Log[3 + Sqrt[3]] - 90 Sqrt[3] Log[3 + Sqrt[3]] -  48 Log[6 + Sqrt[3]] - 52 Sqrt[3] Log[6 + Sqrt[3]] -  72 Log[3 + 2 Sqrt[3]] + 48 Sqrt[3] Log[3 + 2 Sqrt[3]] +  36 Log[9 + 5 Sqrt[3]] - 24 Sqrt[3] Log[9 + 5 Sqrt[3]])/(8 Sqrt[ 3] (19 + 11 Sqrt[3]) (-45 + 26 Sqrt[3])))`

```
N[%]
```

> `0.366623`

Addition. `NIntegrate` produces [a different] the same result if the vertices are taken couunter-clockwise as

```
poly1 = Polygon[{{1, 1/Sqrt[3]}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}}];
NIntegrate[Log[x + y + 1], {x, y} \[Element] poly1]
```

> [`0.17812`]`0.366623`

shows.

Comment: Does it matter whether I define the points in the function `Polygon[]` in clockwise or counter-clockwise manner?

Comment: Now I am confused about the different results for the clockwise and counterclockwise. Why is it different? Which one is the actual value of the integral over the region?

Comment: I get the same result (0.366623) when I integrate over `poly1` and `poly`

Comment: @ArishmanPanigrahi: Yes, you are right. Executing that on a fresh kernel, I obtain the same result.